# XSLT - Comment the grand parent element based on string

Tags: xml, xslt

My Input is like,

```
<part type="backmatter">
<section type="index">
<title>Index<target id="page236"/></title>
<section>
<title>A</title>
........
</listing>
</section>
</section>
</part>
```

Output should be,

```
    <part type="backmatter">
<section type="index">
<title>Index<target id="page236"/></title>
<section>
<title>A</title>
........
</listing>
</section>
</section>
</part>
```

My xslt is like,

```
<xsl:template match="part[@type='backmatter']">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="contains(title[1], 'Index')">
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!--</xsl:text>
<xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/></xsl:copy>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">--&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

While using above mentioned xslt, the output is reflecting as,

```
    <part type="backmatter">
<!--<section type="index">
<title>Index<target id="page236"/></title>
<section>
<title>A</title>
........
</listing>
</section>
</section>-->
</part>
```

We need to comment the "part" elements too which is not required. However, we does not require empty elements.

Comment: Isn't that part following "output should be" identical to the input, with the exception of the indentation of the first tag?

Comment: Oh sorry, the entire code should be comment as shown below.
<!--<part type="backmatter">
<section type="index">
<title>Index<target id="page236"/></title>
<section>
<title>A</title>
........
</listing>
</section>
</section>
</part>-->

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how the posted code would work for a `part` element having a `title` grand child but it sounds as if you want

```
<xsl:template match="part[@type='backmatter' and section/title[contains(., 'Index')]]">
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!--</xsl:text>
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">--&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that moving to XSLT 3 and e.g. Saxon 9.8 allows you to avoid the disable-output-escaping hack and simply use

```
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template match="part[@type='backmatter' and section/title[contains(., 'Index')]]">
   <xsl:comment select="serialize(.)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanku for your response Martin. But my input XML contain 2 different conditions. One is as mentioned on above only "Index" section available in backmatter. In this condition, we need to comment "Index" section with "part" tag. In another condition, other sections title also available in backmatter as shown below.

Comment: <part type="backmatter">
<title><target id="page449"/>Appendix</title>
<section>
<title><target id="page451"/>References</title>
.........
</section>
<section type="index">
<title><target id="page453"/>Index</title>
<section>
<title>A</title>
.......
</section>
</section>
</part>

In this condition, we need to comment only specified "section" which contain "index". title.

Also, I am using "XSLT 2.0" so we don't have option to move the comment part.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the code samples there as formatted code snippets and then explain in more detail which elements you want to comment out and which not and why your code doesn't work.